# Unsafe C# trick to improve speed

Tags: c#, unsafe

I am not used to code with pointers (e.g. C++), nor with unsafe islands: only "safe" C#.
Now I'd like to implement a function in C# for the .Net Micro Framework, where the compactness and the performance are very important.
Basically, I would to collect 4-ples of shorts and thus fill a buffer (e.g. byte-array).
Let's say that every sample is such:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public short An1;
    public short An2;
    public short An3;
    public short An4;
}
```

Each sample is collected via a timer-event, so that I can't loop (there are several reasons).
I have tries many way to efficiently do that, but the most performing seems to be this one:

```
unsafe struct MyStruct2
{
    public fixed byte Buffer[Program.BufferSize];
}


unsafe class Program
{
    public const int BufferSize = 0x1000;
    public const int ArraySize = BufferSize / 8;

    static MyStruct2 _struct2 = new MyStruct2();
    static MyStruct* _structPtr;


    unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int iter = 5000;  //just for simulate many cycles

        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
        {
            //let's make a trick!
            fixed (byte* ptr = _struct2.Buffer)
                _structPtr = (MyStruct*)ptr;

            _structIndex = 0;
            do
            {
                Test5();
            } while (++_structIndex < ArraySize);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    unsafe static void Test5()
    {
        _structPtr->An1 = (short)An1();
        _structPtr->An2 = (short)An2();
        _structPtr->An3 = (short)An3();
        _structPtr->An4 = (short)An4();
        _structPtr++;
    }


    //simulations of ADC reading
    static int An1()
    {
        return 0x1111;
    }

    static int An2()
    {
        return 0x2222;
    }

    static int An3()
    {
        return 0x3333;
    }

    static int An4()
    {
        return 0x4444;
    }
}
```

The improvement over this following safer way -for example- is not so high (177ms vs 224ms), but it is significant anyway.

```
    static MyStruct Test3()
    {
        var data = new MyStruct();
        data.An1 = (short)An1();
        data.An2 = (short)An2();
        data.An3 = (short)An3();
        data.An4 = (short)An4();
        return data;
    }
```

Note: I have cut some code, but I think it's clear enough.

My question is: the "trick" I have made by copying the "fixed" pointer to another unfixed could be reliable or not?...However you can assume that all the data is statically allocated, so should be pinned.
Thank you in advance.
Cheers

Comment: just to clarify, Test3 was faster or Test5?

Comment: Did you measure without the one time JITting? I mean did you try running the managed function once and then measure it in a loop? JITting occurs only once so it would be a bad comparison to the unsafe way if it is included in the sum of time.

Comment: Why are the AnX methods returning an int? Can't you have them return shorts and skip the casts? Does that improve performance? Also, it seems like a really bad idea to take a pointer to a managed buffer out of a `fixed` statement. I'm not sure, but I think that might hurt if the GC gets in the way.

Comment: @jde - there is no jitter, the IL is interpreted.  Abandon all assumptions about efficiency.

Comment: Oh Thanks Hans, I did not know that fact about .NET micro framework...

Comment: I am sorry for the missing info.

Comment: I apologize for the missing info. The Test3 is "safe" but also obviously slower than the unsafe version that is Test5. I have tried 5 different test at all: I have shown only the fastest and the most intuitive. All the test was made on a desktop PC, using the standard .Net framework (consider that the time on the Micro Framework could be 1000 times longer). I can't skip the cast because that is a library function that gives an int, even the useful bits are only 10. Hans is correct: there is not JIT. Feel free to ask more info, as far as I can give you. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mario: *fixed* begins a statement block. Your "block" consists of a single statement, the assignment of the pointer. The purpose of the block is to pin the managed memory for the entire block. After which the managed memory is free to be moved by the GC. I know nothing of Micro Framework, so this may not matter in that environment.

Comment: That's clear, but...assuming that I *never* destroy my _struct2 object, when could be GCed?...I guess that the compiler cannot granted it is pinned, but de-facto it is. About the Micro Framework, there's no difference about these kind of things.

Comment: @Mario "...assuming that I never destroy my _struct2 object" - What do you mean by destroy? C# doesn't have that concept.

Comment: @Mario: The problem is not it being GCed. The problem is that the GC may move it around when compacting the heap, or promoting it to a higher generation. Also, your measurements are not something to guide yourself by, specially given the fact that the Micro Framework is very different from the desktop version. Measure the real values. How do you go about measuring your height? Do you measure your brother and extrapolate from that?

Comment: You're right: the struct allocation may be moved, so the pointer may fail. Thanks for remind me that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code is safe. After `_structPtr = (MyStruct*)ptr` which is within the fixed scope, you then go on to put data into _structPtr on the assumption that _struct2 won't move. Whilst you are correct that it won't be GCed, that doesn't mean that the GC won't move it during memory compaction. The .NET Compact Framework still garbage collects, and I assume it compacts memory rather than leaving it fragmented.

If, for instance, a transient (non static) object allocated on the heap prior to _struct2 is removed by the GC then the memory in use by that struct may be shifted into the free space used by that transient object. At that point _structPtr is pointing to unused memory.

Would modifying Test3() to take a `ref MyStruct data` help?

Also, checkout `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` and `[FieldOffset(...)]` which will allow you to have a single struct with multiple ways of accessing the same data within it. In your case either as 4 bytes or 1 int or (possibly) 1 array of 4 bytes.

Comment: "I don't think the code isn't safe"... Is the double negative intended?

Comment: Thanks Chris. Writing too late at night. Edit upcoming.

Comment: Good idea: I didn't try with "ref". Another idea is to use a "long". I can't use "StructLayout" because it is not available in the Micro Framework libraries. Thanks anyway.

Comment: StructLayout is part of the Micro Framework. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee434399.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270801/how-do-i-change-property-value-in-vb-net/5275398#5275398) from a different posting, on some code I have used extensively. You have the correct idea, just need to set the `FieldOffset()` values, and then use the `fixed()` keyword when accessing the data.

This method is quite reliable, but not really much faster. The reason I use it, is because when I have lots of fields I want a quick way of accessing them as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your "trick" is a problem. Nobody cares how you index memory, or how many offsets you use to accomplish it. I do think you need to heed the advice of others and make sure that you are controlling layout of your struct with StructLayout.Sequential, or .Explicit. Watch the Size and Pack options also.

The other issue, which has been mentioned, is that you need to do all of your work in the fixed block.

```
fixed (byte* ptr = struct2.Buffer)
{
    var structPtr = (MyStruct*)ptr;
    var structIndex = 0;
    do
    {
        Test5(structPtr);
    } while (++structIndex < ArraySize);
}
```

Personally, I think you've stumbled into some Micro-Optimization theatre and would be better served by using safe C# code. Based on the numbers that you have given, (224x10^-3 - 177x10^-3) yields 47ms, divided by 5000 iterations nets you 9.4us (9.4x10^-6) per iteration (assuming windows isn't doing something else at the time).

Comment: The Micro Framework is a tiny subset of the standard one and it has been made for small devices (slow clock, few ram/rom). The timing I have shown was taken on a desktop PC (quite fast), but it was only an indicative ratio between performance. I can't use a closed loop as you suggest, because my cpu is too slow. I guess the only reasonable answer would be create a C++ native custom driver.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by closed loop, but if you have that hard of a real-time requirement (under ~1ms), I doubt that 'C++' is going to help you much. Good Luck.